# How to change inter-lens distance in A-frame?

Tags: aframe, webvr

I don't speak English well... :(

Is it possible to adjust the Inter-lens distance in an Aframe as well as adjust the Inter-lens distance of Google Cardboard Site?

Google Cardboard URL : https://vr.google.com/cardboard/viewerprofilegenerator/

I know this is from the webVR api, is this adjustable in the javascript? ( 
Because the distance between eyes is different for each person, I want to show more accurate screen on cellphone + cardboard. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to change the distance (IPD) in cardboard devices. Lenses are fixed in position. You could potentially manufacture multiple devices with different IPDs.